# Polymer 2 Nested ShadowRoots

Tags: polymer-2.x, shadow-dom

I have a Polymer 2 component that is a parent to multiple Polymer 2 components, each component has it's own shadowRoot.

From the parent component, is it possible to query a node in one of the nested shadowRoots?

I believe you can't have `element > shadowRoot > shadowRoot` but my dom looks like `element > shadowRoot > element > shadowRoot...`

I've tried `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('id')` where `id` is the id of the element (in the nested shadowRoots) that I'm trying to query.

Comment: That should work: `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#container').shadowRoot.querySelector('#id')`

Comment: The issue is not all the child elements with shadowRoots have `id` selectors

Comment: But you can select them by name, no?